# List of sessions for ncftpd per user

Tags: aix

I am dealing with an AIX 7.1 server running ncftpd 2.8.6.

I can count the sessions of established connections counting the number of ncftpd processes.

However, how can I list which ncftpd users are logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For listing the ncftpd users, the command is `ncftpd_spy -n who`

```
# ncftpd_spy -n who
Who                           From                         Num   PID       Idle
user1                         10.1.11.11                  #003 6160428    0:00:00
user2                         10.1.11.12                  #005 5832772    0:00:00
user3                         10.1.11.13                  #009 27590658    0:00:00
user4                         10.1.11.14                  #012 28442788    0:00:00
```